# Rails flexible checklists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I need advice if my approach is right
I would like to create a digital checklist for several test types with the possibility that users can add further questions to the checklist at any time.
I have four models for this. Questions, Checkpoints, CheckTypes and Checks
Question
Users should be able to create questions. Each question has such a check type (name:string checktyp_id:integer) Example Name: "Is enough oil in the tank", checktyp_id:1

Check type
There are basically three types of testing (small, medium and large) Example Name: "Small Check"

Checkpoint
each probe has the following values passed (io:boolean) failed (nio:booelean) OK after repair(inst_io:boolean) the examiner (user_id:integer) test date(check_date:date)
Example: Check_id:integer, Question_id:integer, io:boolean, nio:booelean, inst_io:boolean, user_id:integer, check_date:date

Checks
This is the main form. If the action new is called there, the CheckTyp_id should also be selected.

The behavior of the form:
The Check new action is called with the parameter checktyp_id:1. Now all questions with this checktyp_id should be available in the form. Each question should then have the choices (io, nio, inst_io...) in the form.

The model connections:

```
Question 
->belongs_to check type



Check type 
-> Has_many questions 

Checkpoint 
-> Belongs_to question 
-> Belongs_to check 

Check 
-> has_many questions trough checktyp_id 
-> has_many checkpoints 
-> belongs_to check type
```

Is this correct, or am I thinking too complex?

Comment: I would if possible use more long form and self explainatory names (examiner_id not user_id) and make sure that the names are spelled correctly (CheckTyp_id ??!!) and adhere to the conventions (everything should be `snake_case` except `ClassNames`). https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record

Comment: thanks for the input. Its not coded yet. that is my concept "in head"